# Isotope, cellsbyRow-Layout doesnt initiate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-isotope

i am working on my portfolio and want to use this split-screenlayout that has an isotope grid as content. 
I use the cellsbyRow-Layout which is another plugin from isotope, but for some reason it doesn't work. 
No problems are shown on my console, maybe isotope doesn't work with the split layout?

```
.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}
```

Do you have an idea what could be wrong?
Here is my jsfiddle:

[`http://jsfiddle.net/JuliaJuliaJules/q10n9jqr/16`](http://jsfiddle.net/JuliaJuliaJules/q10n9jqr/16)

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

cellsByRow layout mode is not included in isotope.pkgd.js and must be installed separately. Get it [here](https://raw.github.com/metafizzy/isotope-cells-by-row/master/cells-by-row.js)

Edit: I just looked at the console and I saw `No layout mode: cellsByRow`, so the script is not loading, therefore it is not working.

Comment: it's already included. But still doesn't work. It does work when I take it out of the splitscreen divs. But how do I get it to work inside?

Comment: It's not loading in your jsfiddle, hence the console output `No layout mode: cellsByRow`. The cellsByRow.js script your linking to is not loading into your jsfiddle

Comment: I changed the layout mode, so I don't need the cellsByRow script. But it doesn't even load another layout mode. It seems like Isotope is not working. But it's initiated right, because if I take it out of the  divs panel-container and panel-left it works. But how do I get it to work inside those containers so the grid can be inside my panels.

Comment: Try have ab extra "}" after `layoutMode: 'vertical'`. Remove it and it will work.

Comment: I got it worked out smooth now. 
added 
resize: function() {
      $grid.isotope && $grid.isotope('layout');
in 
  $(".panel-left").resizable({
    handleSelector: "e",
    minWidth: "10%",
    resizeHeight: false,
    resize: function() {
      $grid.isotope && $grid.isotope('layout');
   }
 });
So it reloads layout and adjusts everytime panel-left gets resized.
Thanks for your help!